# Repopulating Jquery multiple selection box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

Here is a [demo](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/examples/jquery-ajax-selection-list/) from a tutorial I followed, with exception it is not in codeigniter so it does not repopulate on reload.

I am using codeigniter which allows me to re-populate the value of forms if there is an error, so if there is a error when submitted the form will reload and remain with the same value (if it the default "0" .city will not appear)....

```
    //.country & .city are slection box, once .country is select it will display 
    // .city and the country cities.

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery(".country").bind("change click", function(){

    var country = jQuery(".country").val();       

    jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/get/locations",
            data: ({country : country }),
            beforeSend: function(){ jQuery("").show(); },  //this is to load an effect (I have empty it for now)
            complete: function(){ jQuery("").hide(); },  
            success: function(response){
                jQuery(".city").html(response);
                if(country=== '0' ){  
                //The default (<option value="0">Select</option>
                    jQuery(".city").hide();
                } else{
                    jQuery(".city").show();
                }
            }
        });
    }).trigger("change");
```

On the last code "trigger("change")", we make sure on page reload the jquery is checked, so if example value 2 (country X) is repopulated by CI it will show the cities of country X without having to change or click.

It is all working perfectly, except that codeigniter can't repopulate the .city selection.
As the values are gotten once the document is ready & codeigniter probably just see blank values within .city select box.

Is there a way I could repopulate the .city with jquery or get codeigniter to repopulate it if there is an error?

A example on how an html could look:

```
<select class="country">
             <option value="0">Select</option>
             <option value="1"> USA </option>
  </select>
  <select class="city" style="display:none;" >
  </select>
```

Comment: this will produce an error ` beforeSend: function(){ jQuery("").show(); }, 
            complete: function(){ jQuery("").hide(); },` as there are no selectors or coz selectors are empty so the whole script wont work, also check `attr('selected','selected')` and `attr('selected','')` should do the trick

Comment: @Val what do you mean? There is Country selectors, city selector gets populated after getting a result from "url: "/get/locations"". I will check that.

Answer (score 0):

If the select is populated correctly (which it sounds like it is), you can trigger the change function with `$('.country').change();`. This will get the `.city` select dropdown repopulated. However, it *will not* select the previously selected city--it will just populate the options.